# Looking for a complete list of Shortcut Keys for Blender 2.8

Tags: interface, workflow

I’m new to the world of Blender and looking for a complete list of Shortcut Keys for Blender 2.8.

Thank you,

Comment: Blender 2.8 Blender Keymap changes: 
https://developer.blender.org/T55162

Comment: Shortcut Keys Changed in 2.8x https://developer.blender.org/T55194

Answer (score 2):

You will find them in the preferences menu. Edit>>Preferences>>Keymap
[image]